# Smart indention on the variable declarations

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I've been searching this forever. So auto-format could have something like this.

```
    const disk      = data.disk < 50 ? 50 : data.disk;
    const diskAdded = data.disk > 50 ? data.disk - 50 : 0;
```

Instead of

```
    const disk = data.disk < 50 ? 50 : data.disk;
    const diskAdded = data.disk > 50 ? data.disk - 50 : 0;
```

And even more fine-grained if this is possible:

```
    const memory    = data.memory < 8  ? 8              : data.memory;
    const diskAdded = data.disk   > 50 ? data.disk - 50 : 0;
```

I would be happy if just the former can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the extension "Better Align" : [Link to Better Align VSCode Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wwm.better-align)

I think this extension is enough to do what you need.

Comment: This extension broke '===' into '==' and '='. I found another one 'auto align' which has no such problem but the indention is not very smart. Some short variable gets big indention when I try to align too many lines of code at once.